# How to put a child div with same size of parent div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: sub div]

[image: Div]

how can I make the child div become with the same size of the parent one, so I can make the hr from side to side of the white box.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row my-row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 my-col">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 my-col" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="centerBlock">
                <hr style="height:0px;border-top:10px solid #7F312B; width:auto;">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="row my-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-7" style="background-color: none;">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KpNE2CS.png" class="img-responsive" style="height: auto; width: 180px; float: left;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-5 helvett cnt" style="background-color: none;">
                        <h3 style="font-size: 18px; color: #5F5F5F;">Novo módulo da nossa plataforma WEB WYIPI</h3>
                        <div style="font-size: 13px; color:#5F5F5F;">A sua nova ferramenta para controlar à distancia, qualquer tipo de processo externo que queira ou exija mais controlo.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row my-row centerBlock">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="button button2 helvett" style="margin-bottom: 25px;margin-top: 45px;"    >Saiba mais</button>
                    </div>                       
                </div>    

            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 my-col">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap because I am going to use this as advertising, so for email it need to be responsive.

Comment: is this for web page or for email? If it's for email, you are basically in the wrong direction, you better read about HTML email.

Comment: remove the padding applied from parent container

Comment: @Yunhai thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the element inside the column a `.row`. It cancels out the padding. Or you can give the element inside the column a margin left and right of -15px yourself. This is the same way `.row` does it.